# Javascript reduce Objects by keys

Tags: javascript

Is there any underscorejs function (or native/custom js function) that transforms this struct :

(please get a look at the real example [@Jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/7gx4gx0n/))

```
//Simple version, check Jsfiddle for the complete one
var object = {
    "users" : [
        {
            name : "name1"
        },
        {
            name : "name2",
        }
    ]
}
```

to another object like this :

```
//Simple version, check Jsfiddle for the complete one
var object2 = {
    users : {
        name : "name1, name2"
    }
}
```

Comment: there isn't one single method for that, but you could combine 2 or 3 that are there to get the job done.

Comment: I couldn't help but wonder, why in god's name would you want to do that.. ( looking at the fiddle )

Comment: object2={users:name: _.pluck(object.users, "name")}}

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This makes the same object as your fiddle:

```
function getType(val){
    if(Object.prototype.toString.call(val) == '[object Array]') return 'array';
    if(val !== null && typeof val === 'object') return 'object';
    return 'other';
}

function deepReduce(object){
    var obj={};
    function travel(object, key, obj){
        if( getType(object) == 'array'){ // if its array, travel
            for(var i=0;i<object.length;i++){
                travel(object[i],key,obj)
            }
        }else if(getType(object)=='object'){ // if its object
            for(var i in object){
                 if(getType(object[i])!='other'){ // if property is object, keep travel
                    if(!obj.hasOwnProperty(i)){
                        obj[i]={};  
                    }
                    travel(object[i],i,obj[i])
                }else{ // else, set property
                    obj[i] =  (obj[i] == undefined ? object[i] : obj[i]+',' + object[i]) ;
                }
            }
        }
    }
    travel(object,null, obj);
    return obj;
}


var reduced=deepReduce(object)
console.log(reduced)
```

Full fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/97g5v5tt/

Comment: No problem, took me a bit longer than expected but was worth it. Good luck with your proyect

Answer (score 0):

You can do it using **map** function

```
object2 = {}
object2.name = object.users.map(function(a){
    return a.name;
}).join(",");
```

Comment: Yes but how could i use this in my [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/7gx4gx0n/) example ?

Comment: if you're returning an array, map() would make more sense than doing extra manip to force reduce() into shape...

Answer (score 0):

Maybe using reduce? It should be available in ES5.

```
var users = [{name: 'Joe'}, {name: 'Anna'}];
var names = users.reduce(function(prev, current) {

    return prev.name + ' ' + current.name;
});
console.log(names); // "Joe Anna"
```

To make this work on your fiddle:
http://jsfiddle.net/Lun8kx2k/

You can reduce other keys as well, or write a function that will recursively check keys and reduce them.
https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/Reduce

Answer (score 0):

Here is a working solution with a little bit less lines of code:

```
Object.deepExtend = function xtend(destination, source) {
    for (var property in source) {
        if (source[property] && source[property].constructor && source[property].constructor === Object) {
            destination[property] = destination[property] || {};
            xtend(destination[property], source[property]);
        } else {
            if (!(destination[property] instanceof Array)) {
                destination[property] = destination[property] == null ? source[property] : [destination[property], source[property]].join(",");
            } else {
                destination[property] = destination[property] == null ? source[property] : destination[property].concat(source[property]);
            }
        }
    }
    return destination;
};

Object.deepExtend(object.users[0], object.users[1])
```

```js
var object = {
    "users" : [
        {
            name : "name1",
            gender : "M",
            age : "18",
            rating : {stars : 5, date : "01.01.2014"},
            articles : [
                {
                    title : "article1",
                    description : "description1"
                },
                {
                    title : "article2",
                    description : "description2"
                }
            ]
        },
        {
            name : "name2",
            gender : "F",
            age : "19",
            rating : {stars : 6, date : "02.01.2014"},
            articles : [
                {
                    title : "article3",
                    description : "description3"
                },
                {
                    title : "article4",
                    description : "description4"
                }
            ]
        }
    ]
}

Object.deepExtend = function xtend(destination, source) {
    for (var property in source) {
        if (source[property] && source[property].constructor && source[property].constructor === Object) {
            destination[property] = destination[property] || {};
            xtend(destination[property], source[property]);
        } else {
            if (!(destination[property] instanceof Array)) {
                destination[property] = destination[property] == null ? source[property] : [destination[property], source[property]].join(",");
            } else {
                destination[property] = destination[property] == null ? source[property] : destination[property].concat(source[property]);
            }
        }
    }
    return destination;
};
document.body.appendChild(document.createElement('pre')).innerHTML = (JSON.stringify(Object.deepExtend(object.users[0], object.users[1]), undefined,3));
```

Comment: But i would like to reduce object to object2 not only the "name" field

Answer (score 0):

This uses lodash (and is only partially complete)... Maybe you could try something like this:

```
var object2 = { users: {} };

_.each(['name', 'gender', 'age'], function (prop) {
  object2.users[prop] = _.pluck(object.users, prop).join(', ');
});

// returns Object { users: { age: "18, 19", gender: "M, F", name: "name1, name2" }}
```

**[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/brbcoding/Lc7qu9q6/2/)**